# Using SAR command to monitor free disk space data

Tags: shell, ssh, command-line, sar

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEhxo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG388.png)> I want to show the usage of disk space for last one hour on graph, for

> that I am creating a API but I want SAR command to execute the listed
> output of disk usage ,I have found the command but it is showing the
> live details of disk usage I have included the image ,I want details
> of last one hour usage, please help or if you have any doubt ask
> me.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEhxo.png)
> In this Image the usage which is showing is live usage

Answer (score 1):

2 years later, but sar has an option for historical data that gets stored in /var/log/sysstat.

There is also a `-s` flag that allows you to set a start time in hh:mm:ss format.

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Create a new directory i.e. /var/log/sardiskusage

Then create a crontab entry:

```
0 * * * *    /usr/bin/sar -F 1 3600 > "/var/log/sardiskusage/$(/usr/bin/date +%s).log"
```

This will run sar -F every second for 3600 seconds (one hour), outputting the output to a new file in /var/log/sardiskusage that gets created by the cronjob entry every hour. You can then reference the file required based on timestamp.